# angular 1.6.1 http request from service

Tags: angularjs

`angular 1.6.1` has removed `.success` and `.error` in service `$http` for use `.then` and `.catch`.
Now my answer is:
It makes sense that I have written in my code? because now I'm confused on how the controller talks to the service

I have a controller for login (example):
**LoginCTRL**

```
User.login(data).then(
   function(response){ 
      //do something    
   },function(err){
     //do somethig
});
```

And I  have **User service**:

```
myapp.service('User', function User($q, $http) {
    return {
            login: function(credentials){
                return $http.post('login',{data:data}).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                    return response;
                }).catch(function onError(response){
                    return response;
                });
            },
}
```

It's correct write **service.method().then** in controller, now that there is no more `$q.defer().resolve(data)` or `$q.defer().reject(reason)`

Comment: you are not using `credentials` in login function line `$http.post('login',{data:data})` and also you have to just return `$http.post('login',{data:credentials})`

Comment: Yes Sorry, my answer is not about  code, but about Logic , It Is roght use .Then in controller After call It in service?

Comment: Not being sure, I think that `User.login(data)` will eventually return you the response from the request. That being said I can't find a reason to add `.then(callback)`.

Comment: Thanks korte, but so, if il woul do something in controller After response service? Example  i would  pronto nane of user in view

Comment: Yes. Its always good to return $http promise to your controller to use `.then()`. So you should just return `$http.post('login',{data:credentials})` which is the good approach.

Comment: It is not clear what is the question. Did you have no problems with using `success` and `$q.defer().resolve()` in the same piece of code in 1.5 and below? Do you have problems now?

Comment: No, i haven't problema, my questions is about if .Then in controller and Also in service It is wrong  , because service not return deferred but directly response

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
myapp.service('User', function User($q, $http) {
      return {
        login: function(credentials) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.post('login', {
            data: data
          }).then(onSuccess, onFailure);

          function onSuccess(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
          }

          function onFailure(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
          }
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).